# dropdownlistfor within a 'for' loop not posting values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have multiple dropdownlists which are rendered with a for loop and I'm having a problem getting them to post the selected value to the controller.  In my query my selectlist is made like this:

```
model.CreateGroupForm.Genders = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "Either", Value = "Either"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Male", Value = "Male"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Female", Value = "Female"},
            };
```

My first problem was even getting my dropdown to display the database value, even though I confirmed it was retrieving the correct value.  It wouldn't work with this:

```
@for (var c = 0; c < Model.ExistingGroups.Count; c++)
     {
      @using (Html.BeginForm("EditGroup", "Group", new { id = Model.Id.StripCollectionName(), slug = Model.Slug, innerid = Model.ExistingGroups[c].Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editcommunityteamform" + c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), @class = "nomarginbottom" }))                                    
      {
      ...
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExistingGroups[c].Gender, Model.Createform.Genders)

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Update name and description of this group">Update</button>
      }
     }
```

After doing some digging on Stack, I discovered that each dropdown rendered needs it's own separate list.  So I changed it to:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExistingGroups[c].Gender,
new SelectList( Model.CreateGroupForm.Genders,"Value", "Text",Model.ExistingGroups[c].Gender))
```

This then correctly displays the queried value, however it just posts null to the controller when I submit the form.  I'm having the same issue with a checkboxfor boolean within the for loop.

My ActionResult in the controller just expects a string value and looks like this:

```
public ActionResult EditGroup(EditGroupInput input)
    {
      var command = new EditGroupCommand(input.Gender);
      ....
```

My view model looks like this:

```
public IList<CommunityGroup> ExistingGroups { get; set; }
public CreateGroupInput CreateGroupForm { get; set; }
```

And then the above 2 classes have the properties mentioned in the code.

Comment: When you said posting null are you doing the same loom in your post action to get the values.

Comment: No there isn't a loop in the actionResult, should there be?  I have edited the OP with what I currently have.

Comment: This looks like ASP.NET MVC and Razor?  Might want to add those tags so you can get the attention of people who know those technologies well.

Comment: you need to have the same loop so you can get the x.ExistingGroups[c].Gender

Comment: I don't really see why.  The submit button should just be posting the value of the dropdown selected.  There is a separate submit button rendered with each dropdown, so each button should post just the value of the dropdown it is associated with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered the problem, which is that dropdownlistfor, checkboxlistfor etc do not like operating within a 'for' loop.  I certainly don't have the technical know-how to understand why, but when I changed dropdownlistfor to dropdownlist it worked.  So the solution looks like this:

```
@for (var c = 0; c < Model.ExistingGroups.Count; c++)
     {
      @using (Html.BeginForm("EditGroup", "Group", new { id = Model.Id.StripCollectionName(), slug = Model.Slug, innerid = Model.ExistingGroups[c].Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editcommunityteamform" + c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), @class = "nomarginbottom" }))                                    
      {
      ...
      @Html.DropDownList("Gender",  new SelectList(Model.CreateGroupForm.Genders, "Value", "Text", Model.ExistingGroups[c].Gender))
     ...
      }
     }
```

Comment: `DropDownListFor()` works perfectly fine in a `for` loop (and using the non strongly typed `DropDownList()` is awful practice). Your problem is you not posting back the same model that you defined in the view. But none of this makes sense anyway - why do you have multiple forms in a loop - you can only post back one form at a time

Comment: Stephen this is an edit page with a line for each group and then an update button at the end of each line.  This gives the user the ability to change any group he wants to.  I know I could just do it with one submit button at the end, but this is how the client wants it.  This is why there are multiple forms on the page.  I have edited the OP with the viewmodel as I'd love to get to the bottom of why I can't get it working with dropdownlistfor.

Comment: Because `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExistingGroups[c].Gender, ...)` generates `<select name="ExistingGroups[#].Gender" ... >` which does not relate to the model your posting back to (which must be a single object, not a collection)

Comment: I see, so since I can't post a collection back to the controller, I guess I'm stuck with using dropdownlist, short of a total redesign.

Answer (score 0):

EditGroupInput should be a collection of ExistingGroups as controller action method are strongly binded with view.or use formcollection as parameter and see what are all the keys being posted from view to controller.